# Extract filename from multiple lines in unix

Tags: sed

I'm trying to extract the name of the file name that has been generated by a Java program. This Java program spits out multiple lines and I know exactly what the format of the file name is going to be. The information text that the Java program is spitting out is as follows:

```
ABCASJASLEKJASDFALDSF
Generated file  YANNANI-0008876_17.xml. 
TDSFALSFJLSDJF;
```

I'm capturing the output in a variable and then applying a sed operator in the following format:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(YANNANI.\([[:digit:]]\).\([xml]\)*\)/\1/p'
```

The result set is:

```
YANNANI-0008876_17.xml.
```

However, my problem is that want the extraction of the filename to stop at `.xml`. The last dot should never be extracted.

Is there a way to do this using sed?

Comment: If you have control over the Java program, make it write machine-readable output (maybe JSON, or XML if you have to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what your capture group actually captures:

```
$ grep 'YANNANI.\([[:digit:]]\).\([xml]\)*' infile
Generated file  YANNANI-0008876_17.xml.
```

That's probably not what you intended:

- `\([[:digit:]]\)` captures just a single digit (and the capture group around it doesn't do anything)
- `\([xml]\)*` is "any of `x`, `m` or `l`, 0 or more times", so it matches the empty string (as above – or the line wouldn't match at all!), `x`, `xx`, `lll`, `mxxxxxmmmmlxlxmxlmxlm`, `xml`, ...
- There is no way the final period is removed because you don't match anything after the capture groups

What would make sense instead:

- Match "digits or underscores, 0 or more": `[[:digit:]_]*`
- Match `.xml`, literally (escape the period): `\.xml`
- Make sure the rest of the line (just the period, in this case) is matched by adding `.*` after the capture group

So the regex for the string you'd like to extract becomes

```
$ grep 'YANNANI.[[:digit:]_]*\.xml' infile
Generated file  YANNANI-0008876_17.xml.
```

and to remove everything else on the line using sed, we surround regex with `.*\( ... \).*`:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\(YANNANI.[[:digit:]_]*\.xml\).*/\1/p' infile
YANNANI-0008876_17.xml
```

This assumes you really meant `.` after `YANNANI` (any character).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. That helped me to understand the regexp as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can call sed **twice**: first in **printing** and then in **replacement** mode:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(YANNANI.\([[:digit:]]\).\([xml]\)*\)/\1/p' | sed 's/\.$//g'
```

the last sed will remove all the last `.` at the end of all the lines fetched by your first sed

or you can go for a `awk` solution as you prefer:

```
awk '/.*YANNANI.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.xml/{print substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1)}'
```

this will print the last field (and truncate the last char of it using `substr`) of all the lines that do match your regex.

Comment: Thanks Allan. That was helpful as well.

Comment: It's a pleasure to help! if we were able to solve your problem, you can choose a solution or vote up the answer! :-)